# Calculation of adiabatic expansion using partial derivatives

Tags: thermodynamics, adiabatic

Let's consider a gas for now (since we can generalise this result to other systems trivially).

I want to calculate the change in temperature when the gas expands adiabatically.  I am taught that I can find it simply by calculating the partial derivative of T with respect to V, holding S constant.

However, an adiabatic process is defined that it must be reversible (which is constrained by holding S constant) AND it must involve no transfer of heat to or from the surroundings.  How do I know that the latter is satisfied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The change in entropy is determined by the integral of dq/T for a reversible path.  If dq is equal to zero, which is the definition of an adiabatic path, then $\Delta S$ is zero.  Is that what you were asking about?

Comment: Hmm perhaps it answers half of my question... but what about the reverse: if I'm calculating the the partial derivative of T with respect to V, holding S constant, how do I know that I am dealing with a process that is necessarily an adiabatic expansion? (couldn't I be calculating the change in T when I change V in other reversible processes)

Comment: by the way your answer told me that constraining there's no heat transfer tells me that there's no entropy change.  However, I'm asking about how does constraining no entropy change means no heat transfer (the reverse).

Comment: When it is expressed in terms of the differential in T, the implication is that the change is reversible.  Otherwise T is not necessarily uniform spatially throughout the system.  So which spatial value of T would the equation be referring to?

Comment: Ok, so by holding S constant, we know that it is reversible.  However, how do I know that there's no heat transfer? (I need to know that there's no heat transfer to determine that it's adiabatic)

Comment: Your problem statement says that the expansion is adiabatic and reversible.  So the change in entropy had to be zero over every increment along the path.

Comment: Oh ok... thanks!!! Another point I want to make clear is that: does reversible processes always have dS=0?

Comment: No.  Only for an adiabatic reversible process is this guaranteed at every increment along the process path.  Of course there are an infinite number of reversible paths for which dS is not zero.